# Downloading excel file using ExcelJS and node js not being downloaded in any browser

Tags: node.js, angular, exceljs

I was trying to send `.xlsx` file using `exceljs` and `nodejs` to the client as a downloadable file. So far I'm able to create `employees.xlsx` file but it's not triggering save file dialog in the browser. Here's what I've tried in my backend API:

My Controller:

```
exports.exportEmployees = async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const employees = await Employee.find();
    let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("Employees");
    worksheet.columns = [
      { header: "Employee Name", key: "fullName", width: 40 },
      { header: "Department", key: "departmentName", width: 25 },
      { header: "Position", key: "positionName", width: 25 },
    ];

    worksheet.addRows(employees);

    res.setHeader(
      "Content-Type",
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    );
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=employees.xlsx");

    // This doesn't work either
    // workbook.xlsx.write(res).then(function () {
    //   res.status(200).end();
    // });

    workbook.xlsx.writeFile("./employees.xlsx").then(
      (response) => {
        console.log("File is created"); // I'm able to see this in my console
        console.log(path.join(__dirname, "../employees.xlsx"));
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../employees.xlsx"));
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log("ERROR: ", err);
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ errors: err });
  }
};
```

And in my route.js

```
router.get("/employee-excel", auth, exportExcelController.exportEmployees);

module.exports = router;
```

So, the problem I'm facing now is whenever I call the api from my Angular app the browser response is a binary code.

Angular service to call the API

```
generateEmployeeExcel(query: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.serverReportAPI}/employee-excel`, {
      params: query,
      headers: this.tokenHelperService.getAuthToken().headers,
    });
  }
```

My component

```
this.reportService.generateEmployeeExcel(query).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    console.log("Are we getting here?", response); // not able to get here
    this.isLoading = false;
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log("Is there any error?", err); // This is displayed in console

    this.isLoading = false;
  }
);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

The response in my browser
[image]

Comment: You could try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver to save the blob as a file and prompt download in the user's browser

Comment: Do you mean in my angular app?

Comment: @Kirubel is your api working as expected. when you hit api url in browser, does it prompt to download?

Comment: @NileshPatel Yes it's working as intended. But as the image I tried to post on the question, the response is something binary.

Comment: Yes, it basically does the same as the custom code below that creates the download link and clicks it, but I would consider a better option as it has more optimisations for different browsers and contexts, so you don't need to worry about the manual IE modifications etc. The whole package is around 170 lines of code: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/src/FileSaver.js

Comment: @chrismclarke thanks, and I've read about the file-saver and worked like a charm for me. :)

Comment: that's great, glad you were able to get it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change http code to :-

```
generateEmployeeExcel(query: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.serverReportAPI}/employee-excel`, {
      params: query,
      headers: this.tokenHelperService.getAuthToken().headers,
      responseType: 'blob'
    });
  }
```

**For subscribe and download :-**

```
this.reportService.generateEmployeeExcel(query).subscribe(
  (res) => {
        console.log("Are we getting here?", res); // not able to get here
        this.isLoading = false;
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(res.data);
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "employee.xlsx";
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        a.remove();
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log("Is there any error?", err); // This is displayed in console

    this.isLoading = false;
  }
);
```

**If support for IE is required :-**

```
this.reportService.generateEmployeeExcel(query).subscribe(
  (res) => {
        console.log("Are we getting here?", res); // not able to get here
     if(window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
         window.nagigator.msSaveBlob(res, "employee.xlsx");
         return;
     }
        this.isLoading = false;
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(res.data);
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "employee.xlsx";
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        a.remove();
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log("Is there any error?", err); // This is displayed in console

    this.isLoading = false;
  }
);
```

Comment: One thing if you could also help me, how can I make the save file dialog pop on the browser?

Comment: @Kirubel please check modifications i made for IE as well.

Comment: @AakashGarg I have a similar issue. I used your code for the subscribe and download method. The file does get downloaded. But it is of size 0k. And when I click on it I get Excel error that the file format is not correct or it is corrupted.  Would you please look at this thread: ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66369799/exceljs-why-workbook-xlsx-writeres-is-not-downloading-the-file ```   It would be of great help.